# Help me understand the different parts of journalctl´s error code

Tags: error-handling, systemd-journald

Journalctl's output may look like this:

```
maj 01 10:13:02 kontor pulseaudio[1198]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Trying to understand the different parts of the error message, apart from the error code itself

That it presents from the left counted

```
Date / Time - Hostname - Program
```

that it is OK, 
but now not fully aware what (in this case) `[1198]` means 
and how I can use it in the troubleshooting?

And why `[Pulseaudio]` is in brackets the second time?

then `pid.c`: in front of the colon.

Has search a lot without finding almost anything on the web.

I think that `[1198]` is a upstartnumber (given by the system) but I can't find how to use?

can anyone help me out here, or link to a web page that explains this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
maj 01 10:13:02 kontor pulseaudio[1198]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
^--date--time-^ ^host^ ^prcesname^^PID^: ^program generated content................^
```

`prcesname` is really `Process Name`, and `PID` is the `Process ID`. The `program generated content` is produced by the program (`pulseaudio` in this case), and can be anything. Here, the `[pulseaudio]` program, inside it's `pid.c` module, found that the (`pulseaudio`) daemon was already running, causing the attempt to Start a daemon to fail.

See `man logger;man 3 syslog;man -k pid`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. is it possible to use the PID number in a terminal command to get more information.

Comment: Yes. Read the `man` pages. Add `man ps` to your reading list.